# Layer normalization and how it works (tensorflow)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a hard time understanding layer normalization. Let's say I trained a model in tensorflow. When I check the variables of the graph, I get the following:

```
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense/kernel:0' shape=(5, 64) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm/beta:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm/gamma:0' shape=(64,) type=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(64, 64) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_1/bias:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm_1/beta:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/LayerNorm_1/gamma:0' shape=(64,) dtype=float32_ref>
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_2/kernel:0' shape=(64, 1) dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'actor/dense_2/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

As you see it is a two-layer fully-connected network with layer normalization in each layer.

So, I know that the biases are added to the node inputs. Do the variables actor/LayerNorm/beta:0, actor/LayerNorm/gamma:0 etc. work the same way? Can I just summarize the biases, beta and gamma values for one layer as one "bias" vector? Or is it a complete different mechanism?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see this is your first question on stackoverflow. In order to give you a good answer, can you tell us what you tried to figure this out already? What do you know about the purpose of layer normalization?

Comment: Well, I read the paper by Ba et al. What I got from it, is that apparently layer norm speeds up the training process. However, I couldn't find anything about the beta and gamma variables created by tensorflow. In the tensorflow documentation about tc.layers.layer_norm I read the following:

Comment: "By default, begin_norm_axis = 1 and begin_params_axis = -1, meaning that normalization is performed over all but the first axis (the HWC if inputs is NHWC), while the beta and gamma trainable parameters are calculated for the rightmost axis (the C if inputs is NHWC). Scaling and recentering is performed via broadcast of the beta and gamma parameters with the normalized tensor." However, I have no idea what this suppose to mean. If we think about the beta and gamma variables as vectors: Are their elements just added to the neuron inputs just as is the case with biases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beta and gamma variables are different than the bias variables. The code is something like this:

```
y = tf.matmul(kernel, x) + bias
mean, variance = tf.nn.moments(y, [1], keep_dims=True)
normalized_y = (y - mean) / tf.sqrt(variance + 1e-5)
y_out = normalized_y * gamma + beta
```

First you multiply the kernel with the input `x` and add the bias term. Then you compute the mean and variance of the values in the vector `y`. You normalize `y` by subtracting the mean value and dividing by the total standard deviation. Finally, you adjust y by multiplying each dimension with gamma and adding beta.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: could you justify the choice of the axes = [1] in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead to use the implementation provided by the contributors in the tensorflow official repo. 
Here is the [layer normalization implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/layer_norm)